# Setup of Citrix-Client (xenapp) doesn't work on Windows Vista Utimate

Tags: windows-vista

I have a notebook with a fully patched Vista Ultimate and there was a Citrix ica-client installed for access on our citrix-server(s).

Once the client couldn't access the server – it took so much time (> 5 min) and everything froze. I did an uninstall und cleaned up the registry.

But now it's not possible to reinstall a xenapp-client even the newest directly from www.citrix.com.

- What could be the reason?
- How to fix this issue?

PS: At the moment I start a vm with an XP and the citrix-access runs like a charm, but that only could be a work-a-round.

Comment: Can you try this one: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116552

Comment: I think i'm missing this:  "Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86) ". I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint, it must have been the "Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package (x86)" which was missing.

It works now as expected.